# How to animate and switch between texts and images?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

all the problems started after adding the images part.  before that the texts switched fine with the fading. but now after adding the images the texts show twice in a row before switching and the images not switching fine.  one image in the hierarchy is black color one is white and the first time it does switching fine everything but then next times everything switch only after twice in a row and the images after the first time never show the black one anymore.

this is image screenshot of the hierarchy settings:

[image: hierarchy]

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DatesAnimation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_Text firstTextMesh;
    public TMP_Text secondTextMesh; // Reference to the second text object
    public Image firstImage; // Reference to the first background image
    public Image secondImage; // Reference to the second background image
    public float animSpeedInSec = 1f;
    bool keepAnimating = false;

    private string firstNumber = "4.11.1995";
    private string secondNumber = "7.10.2023";
    private string firstString = "אתה"; // First string for the second text
    private string secondString = "אשם"; // Second string for the second text
    private bool isDisplayingFirstImage = true; // Track which image is displayed

    private void Start()
    {
        // Set initial text
        firstTextMesh.text = firstNumber;
        secondTextMesh.text = ReverseString(firstString);

        // Set initial image to be visible and the other to be transparent
        firstImage.color = new Color(firstImage.color.r, firstImage.color.g, firstImage.color.b, 1f);
        secondImage.color = new Color(secondImage.color.r, secondImage.color.g, secondImage.color.b, 0f);

        startTextMeshAnimation();
    }

    private IEnumerator anim()
    {
        // Colors at full opacity
        Color visibleColorFirst = new Color(firstTextMesh.color.r, firstTextMesh.color.g, firstTextMesh.color.b, 1);
        Color visibleColorSecond = new Color(secondTextMesh.color.r, secondTextMesh.color.g, secondTextMesh.color.b, 1);
        Color visibleColorFirstImage = new Color(firstImage.color.r, firstImage.color.g, firstImage.color.b, 1);
        Color visibleColorSecondImage = new Color(secondImage.color.r, secondImage.color.g, secondImage.color.b, 1);

        // Colors at zero opacity (transparent)
        Color invisibleColor = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);

        while (keepAnimating)
        {
            // Fade out both texts and images
            for (float counter = 0; counter < animSpeedInSec; counter += Time.deltaTime)
            {
                if (!keepAnimating) yield break;
                firstTextMesh.color = Color.Lerp(visibleColorFirst, invisibleColor, counter / animSpeedInSec);
                secondTextMesh.color = Color.Lerp(visibleColorSecond, invisibleColor, counter / animSpeedInSec);
                firstImage.color = Color.Lerp(visibleColorFirstImage, invisibleColor, counter / animSpeedInSec);
                secondImage.color = Color.Lerp(visibleColorSecondImage, invisibleColor, counter / animSpeedInSec);

                yield return null;
            }

            // Toggle texts
            firstTextMesh.text = firstTextMesh.text == firstNumber ? secondNumber : firstNumber;
            secondTextMesh.text = secondTextMesh.text == ReverseString(firstString) ? ReverseString(secondString) : ReverseString(firstString);

            // Toggle images visibility
            isDisplayingFirstImage = !isDisplayingFirstImage;

            // Fade in both texts and the current image
            for (float counter = 0; counter < animSpeedInSec; counter += Time.deltaTime)
            {
                if (!keepAnimating) yield break;
                firstTextMesh.color = Color.Lerp(invisibleColor, visibleColorFirst, counter / animSpeedInSec);
                secondTextMesh.color = Color.Lerp(invisibleColor, visibleColorSecond, counter / animSpeedInSec);

                if (isDisplayingFirstImage)
                {
                    firstImage.color = Color.Lerp(invisibleColor, visibleColorFirstImage, counter / animSpeedInSec);
                    secondImage.color = invisibleColor; // Keep second image invisible
                }
                else
                {
                    secondImage.color = Color.Lerp(invisibleColor, visibleColorSecondImage, counter / animSpeedInSec);
                    firstImage.color = invisibleColor; // Keep first image invisible
                }

                yield return null;
            }
        }
    }

    //Call to Start animation
    void startTextMeshAnimation()
    {
        if (keepAnimating)
        {
            return;
        }
        keepAnimating = true;
        StartCoroutine(anim());
    }

    private void FadeImages(float lerpFactor, bool fadeIn)
    {
        if (fadeIn)
        {
            // Fade in the current image and fade out the other
            if (isDisplayingFirstImage)
            {
                firstImage.color = new Color(firstImage.color.r, firstImage.color.g, firstImage.color.b, lerpFactor);
                secondImage.color = new Color(secondImage.color.r, secondImage.color.g, secondImage.color.b, 1 - lerpFactor);
            }
            else
            {
                secondImage.color = new Color(secondImage.color.r, secondImage.color.g, secondImage.color.b, lerpFactor);
                firstImage.color = new Color(firstImage.color.r, firstImage.color.g, firstImage.color.b, 1 - lerpFactor);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Fade out the current image and fade in the other
            if (isDisplayingFirstImage)
            {
                firstImage.color = new Color(firstImage.color.r, firstImage.color.g, firstImage.color.b, 1 - lerpFactor);
                secondImage.color = new Color(secondImage.color.r, secondImage.color.g, secondImage.color.b, lerpFactor);
            }
            else
            {
                secondImage.color = new Color(secondImage.color.r, secondImage.color.g, secondImage.color.b, 1 - lerpFactor);
                firstImage.color = new Color(firstImage.color.r, firstImage.color.g, firstImage.color.b, lerpFactor);
            }
        }
    }

    //Call to Change animation Speed
    void changeTextMeshAnimationSpeed(float animSpeed)
    {
        animSpeedInSec = animSpeed;
    }

    //Call to Stop animation
    void stopTextMeshAnimation()
    {
        keepAnimating = false;
    }

    private string ReverseString(string s)
    {
        char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(charArray);
        return new string(charArray);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you referring to the anim routine or the FadeImages function that is being called from somewhere else?  Your anim routine keeps setting the color back to the visible color every loop, not sure if that is intended, seems to fade in/out though.